# Execute a loop on a POST request on Node.js server

Tags: node.js, post, asynchronous, foreach, callback

im trying to count how many people of every gender are there in a json list passed by the client with a POST request (on Node.js server). I have problems understanding javascript asynchronization, callbacks and closures.

What i want is:
getting a list from the client, 
for every entry ask my collection if that is a m, a f or a u,
count how many fs, ms and us there are,
send an array to the client with the three values.

I always get "Cant set headers after they are sent" or similar errors due to async execution. I tried different callback orders and many different options.

This is how the functions on the server looks like:

```
app.post('/genderize', function(req, res){
        createCounter("conto", req, function(req,contat ){
            count(req, contat);
        }).then(res.send( result ));
    });

function createCounter( nome, req, callback ) {
        result = [0,0,0];
        var contatore = function(){
            var m = 0;
            var f = 0;
            var u = 0;

            addM = function(){ console.log( "m++ "+result[1]);result[1]++; };
            addF = function(){ f++; };
            addU = function(){ u++; };

            getM = function(){ return this.m;};

            getResult = function(){
                console.log( result+ " *  "+ getM() + "  *  " + this.u + "  *  "+ this.f );
                return result;
            };
            return {
                addM: addM,
                addF: addF,
                addU: addU,
                getResult: getResult
                }; 
        }
            callback( req, contatore() );
    }

function count( req, counter ){
        var collection = db.get('nomi');
        var data = req.body.data;
        data.forEach(function(value, i){
            collection.find({ nome : req.body.data[i].name.split(" ")[0].toUpperCase() }, { fields: {_id:0, nome:0}}, function (err, docs) {
                        if (!isEmptyObject(docs)) {
                            docs = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(docs));;
                            if(docs[0].sesso == "M"){                   
                                counter.addM();
                            } else {
                                counter.addF();
                            }
                        } else {
                            counter.addU();
                        }
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: First of all, createCounter is not a promise, so you should remove the then.

Comment: Can you paste what your JSON from the client looks like?

Comment: The script iterates trough the JSON without problems, its not that. Should i make a promise? before putting the "then" i called res.send as a callback of count but it didnt wait

Comment: It didn't wait since it is immediately called during execution, not after all the documents have been retrieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with this example, but the main thing that you missed is that when you perform your database query, the `collection.find` call will return immediately, but will only execute its callback (`function(err, docs)`) at some later time after the database has replied.

Here's a working rewrite:

```
app.post('/genderize', function(req, res) {
    if (!req.body.data || req.body.data.length === undefined) {
        return res.status(400).send('Invalid request body.');
    }
    countGenders(db.get('nomi'), req.body.data, function (err, genders) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send('Unable to process request.');
        res.send([genders.M, genders.F, genders.U]);
    });
});

function getGenderFromName(collection, name, next) {
    collection.find({nome : name.split(" ")[0].toUpperCase()}, {fields: {_id:0, nome:0}}, function (err, docs) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        var gender = 'U';
        if (docs && docs.length > 0) {
            gender = (docs[0].sesso == "M") ? 'M' : 'F';
        }
        next(null, gender);       
    });
}

function countGenders(collection, data, next) {
    var result = { M: 0, F: 0, U: 0 };
    var series = function(i) {
        if (i == data.length) return next(null, result);
        getGenderFromName(collection, data[i].name, function(err, gender) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            result[gender]++;
            series(i+1);
        });
    };
    series(0);
}
```

Lets review the changes:

- Removed the `createCounter` structure. No need for a heavy, get/set pattern for this simple example.
- Checked for error values in every asynchronous callback

  ```
  if (err) return next(err);
  ```

  Within a route handler, typically you will want to end the request with a `res.status(500).send()`. In most other cases, `return next(err)` will 'bubble' the error up.
- Moved the database query into a new function, `getGenderFromName`. It mostly retains your original code. This was optional, but substantially improves the readability of the `count` function.
- Finally, rewrote the `count` function using an appropriate asynchronous iteration pattern, courtesy of http://book.mixu.net/node/ch7.html. Mixu gives a very easy to understand explanation of asynchronous node, give it a read.

  An even better option would be use the excellent [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module. You could rewrite the `count` method as

  ```
  function countGenders(collection, data, next) {
      var result = { M: 0, F: 0, U: 0 };
      async.eachSeries(
          data,
          function (value, next) {
              getGenderFromName(collection, value.name, function(err, gender) {
                  if (err) return next(err);
                  result[gender]++;
                  next();
              });
          },
          function (err) { next(err, results); }
      );
  }
  ```

  Async includes lots of different control flow methods to use, not just simple iterations.

Comment: Yeah this works! I'll check the aync module documentation and mixu's chapter. thank you for your help

Comment: Glad to help and good luck, node async is difficult pattern to understand at first so just keep at it until it clicks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better way to do this. This really cleans up the asynchronous nature of javascript. Checkout the async library that I am using here.

```
var collection = db.get('nomi');
var async = require('async');

app.post('/genderize', function(req, res){
    let countingObject = {
        females: 0,
        males: 0,
        unknown: 0
    };

    async.each(req.body.data, function(name, callback) {
        collection.findOne({ nome : name.split(" ")[0].toUpperCase() }, { fields: {_id:0, nome:0}}, function (err, nameObject) {
            //instead, maybe check if it is male, female, or otherwise mark as unknown?
            if (!isEmptyObject(nameObject)) {
                //this object probably has getters that you could use instead
                nameObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(nameObject));
                if(nameObject.sesso == "M"){                   
                    countingObject.males++;
                } else {
                    countingObject.females++;
                }
            } else {
                countingObject.unknown++;
            }
            callback();
        });
    }, function() {
        res.setHeader('Content-Header', 'application/json');
        res.send(JSON.stringify(countingCallback));
    });
});
```

Comment: I forgot to add the 'callback()', but added it in. Notice how it only calls res.send until after all the names are iterative over, and after their corresponding 'nome' is found from the database.

Comment: I think async.each is what i was looking for! Anyway this returns an unexpected identifier errror on countingObject line 5 of your script. 
Why do you use the kwyword let?

Comment: Ah, you probably haven't upgraded node, or are not using 'use strict';. You can use var instead

Comment: I get error 500 using var, anyway i made everything working using the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34229446/5036031 ! thanks for your help